# Set Position of Text Field in Java?

Tags: java, position, jtextfield

I'm currently writing a program that requires user input within the Frame.  Is there a simple way to set the position of an input text field (in X and Y coordinates)?  The constructor and mutator methods of the JTextField doesn't seem to be able to do this.

This is the code:

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.net.*;

class labMain extends Frame implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    String screenState;

    Color bfi = new Color(155, 48, 255);
    Color bfh = new Color(155, 48, 255, 200);
    Color bfs = new Color(155, 48, 255, 200);
    Color bbi = new Color(255, 255, 255);
    Color bbh = new Color(5, 12, 15);
    Color bbs = new Color(220, 20, 60);

    quadButton startSession, gotoUser, gotoInventory, gotoCalendar, gotoProcedures, gotoResults, gotoEmergencies;

    quadButton addUsers, findUsers;

    int mouseX, mouseY;

    javax.swing.Timer mainT;

    BufferedImage imageBuffer;
    Graphics2D  graphicsBuffer;
    boolean[] keys = new boolean[525];

    public labMain() {

        setTitle("uwDNA Lab Pro");
        setSize(new Dimension(1365, 765));

        this.addWindowListener (

                new WindowAdapter() {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        labMain.this.windowClosed();
                    }
                }

        );

        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    protected void windowClosed() { System.exit(0); }

    public void runLab() throws IOException {

        imageBuffer = (BufferedImage) createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
        graphicsBuffer = (Graphics2D) imageBuffer.getGraphics();

        screenState = "Main";

        mainScreenInit();
        usersScreenInit();
        addUsersScreenInit();

        ActionListener mainS = new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                detectMouseHover();

                paint(getGraphics());

            }

        };

        mainT = new javax.swing.Timer(1, mainS);
        mainT.start();

    }

    public void detectMouseHover() {

        if (startSession.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            startSession.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            startSession.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (gotoUser.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            gotoUser.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            gotoUser.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (gotoInventory.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            gotoInventory.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            gotoInventory.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (gotoCalendar.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            gotoCalendar.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            gotoCalendar.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (gotoProcedures.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            gotoProcedures.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            gotoProcedures.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (gotoResults.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            gotoResults.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            gotoResults.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (gotoEmergencies.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            gotoEmergencies.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            gotoEmergencies.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (addUsers.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            addUsers.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            addUsers.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

        if (findUsers.intersects(mouseX, mouseY)) {

            findUsers.setState(aButton.isHover);

        }

        else {

            findUsers.setState(aButton.isIdle);

        }

    }

    public void mainScreenInit() {

        startSession = new quadButton(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, 400, 200, 10, Font.BOLD, 40, "Start Lab Session", "Arial", bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);

        int bbWidth = 200;
        int bbHeight = bbWidth / 2;
        int bbFontStyle = Font.PLAIN;
        int bbFontSize = 20;
        int bbBorderWidth = 5;
        String bbFontName = "Arial";

        gotoUser = new quadButton(((getWidth() - bbWidth * 6) / 7) * 1 + (bbWidth / 2 * 1), (getHeight() * 3 / 4) + 20, bbWidth, bbHeight, bbBorderWidth, bbFontStyle, bbFontSize, "Users", bbFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);
        gotoInventory = new quadButton(((getWidth() - bbWidth * 6) / 7) * 2 + (bbWidth / 2 * 3), (getHeight() * 3 / 4) + 20, bbWidth, bbHeight, bbBorderWidth, bbFontStyle, bbFontSize, "Inventory", bbFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);
        gotoCalendar = new quadButton(((getWidth() - bbWidth * 6) / 7) * 3 + (bbWidth / 2 * 5), (getHeight() * 3 / 4) + 20, bbWidth, bbHeight, bbBorderWidth, bbFontStyle, bbFontSize, "Calendar", bbFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);
        gotoProcedures = new quadButton(((getWidth() - bbWidth * 6) / 7) * 4 + (bbWidth / 2 * 7), (getHeight() * 3 / 4) + 20, bbWidth, bbHeight, bbBorderWidth, bbFontStyle, bbFontSize, "Procedures", bbFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);
        gotoResults = new quadButton(((getWidth() - bbWidth * 6) / 7) * 5 + (bbWidth / 2 * 9), (getHeight() * 3 / 4) + 20, bbWidth, bbHeight, bbBorderWidth, bbFontStyle, bbFontSize, "Results", bbFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);
        gotoEmergencies = new quadButton(((getWidth() - bbWidth * 6) / 7) * 6 + (bbWidth / 2 * 11), (getHeight() * 3 / 4) + 20, bbWidth, bbHeight, bbBorderWidth, bbFontStyle, bbFontSize, "Emergencies", bbFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);

    }

    public void usersScreenInit() {

        int ubWidth = 400;
        int ubHeight = ubWidth / 2;
        int ubFontStyle = Font.BOLD;
        int ubFontSize = 20;
        int ubBorderWidth = 10;
        String ubFontName = "Arial";

        addUsers = new quadButton(((getWidth() - ubWidth * 2) / 3) * 1 + (ubWidth / 2 * 1), (getHeight() * 9 / 16) + 20, ubWidth, ubHeight, ubBorderWidth, ubFontStyle, ubFontSize, "Add Users", ubFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);
        findUsers = new quadButton(((getWidth() - ubWidth * 2) / 3) * 2 + (ubWidth / 2 * 3), (getHeight() * 9 / 16) + 20, ubWidth, ubHeight, ubBorderWidth, ubFontStyle, ubFontSize, "Find Users", ubFontName, bfi, bfh, bfs, bbi, bbh, bbs);

    }

    public void addUsersScreenInit() {



    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {



    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {



    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {



    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {



    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {



    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {



    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (screenState == "Main") {

            if (gotoUser.intersects(e.getX(), e.getY())) {

                screenState = "Users";

            }

        }

        if (screenState == "Users") {

            if (addUsers.intersects(e.getX(), e.getY())) {

                screenState = "addUsers";

            }

        }

    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {



    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        Color bkgBlue = new Color(102, 170, 205);

        graphicsBuffer.setColor(bkgBlue);
        graphicsBuffer.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        setBackground(bkgBlue);

        BufferedImage bkg;

        if (screenState.equals("Main")) {

            try {

                graphicsBuffer.setColor(Color.white);
                graphicsBuffer.fillRect((getWidth() / 2) - 455, (getHeight() / 2) - 355, 910, 175);

                URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/iLm99QZ.jpg?1?9353");
                bkg = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(url);
                graphicsBuffer.drawImage(bkg, (getWidth() / 2) - 450, (getHeight() / 2) - 350, this);

            }
            catch (IOException e) { System.err.println(e); }

            startSession.paint(graphicsBuffer);
            gotoUser.paint(graphicsBuffer);
            gotoInventory.paint(graphicsBuffer);
            gotoCalendar.paint(graphicsBuffer);
            gotoProcedures.paint(graphicsBuffer);
            gotoResults.paint(graphicsBuffer);
            gotoEmergencies.paint(graphicsBuffer);

        }

        if (screenState.equals("Users")) {

            try {

                graphicsBuffer.setColor(Color.white);
                graphicsBuffer.fillRect((getWidth() / 2) - 455, (getHeight() / 2) - 355, 910, 175);

                URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/nUrYx7q.jpg?1");
                bkg = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(url);
                graphicsBuffer.drawImage(bkg, (getWidth() / 2) - 450, (getHeight() / 2) - 350, this);

            }
            catch (IOException e) { System.err.println(e); }

            addUsers.paint(graphicsBuffer);
            findUsers.paint(graphicsBuffer);

        }

        if (screenState.equals("addUsers")) {

            try {

                graphicsBuffer.setColor(Color.white);
                graphicsBuffer.fillRect((getWidth() / 2) - 455, (getHeight() / 2) - 355, 910, 175);

                URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/GDCTw65.jpg?1");
                bkg = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(url);
                graphicsBuffer.drawImage(bkg, (getWidth() / 2) - 450, (getHeight() / 2) - 350, this);

            }
            catch (IOException e) { System.err.println(e); }

        }

        g2.drawImage(imageBuffer, 10, 25, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);

    }

}
```

Comment: What LayoutManager are you using for the containing component?

Comment: Absolute positioning (choosing the EXACT location based off X-Y coords) is frowned upon. You should look into Layout Managers, which allows your components to get laid out in a proper fashion so visuals appear the same on all platforms. However, if you MUST, you can set the container's layout to `null`, then either use `setBounds` or `setLocation`.

Comment: `Is there a simple way to set the position of an input text field (in X and Y coordinates)?` - don't do this!!! You code won't work as expected on different platforms that may use different fonts etc. Also, scrolling won't work. There are many reasons NOT do to this. Swing was designed to be used with `Layout Managers`.

Comment: I don't believe I'm using a LayoutManager.  I've been positioning components relative to getWidth() and getHeight() so far.  So things like getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 positions things in the center of the Frame.

Edit: This program is intended for internal use, so it will only be used on one computer.  The basic function of the program is to track research laboratory work and inventory (register users, track stock chemicals, etc.)  We're only using it in our lab, so the working on different platforms things isn't too big of an issue I think.

Comment: `I don't believe I'm using a LayoutManager` - that is the problem, you should be using a layout manager. A layout manager can automatically center components for you. For example the default behaviour of the `GridBagLayout` is to center the components horizontally and vertically. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: `I don't believe I'm using a LayoutManager` in fact you probabaly are. From [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) "Each `JPanel` object is initialized to use a `FlowLayout`, unless you specify differently when creating the `JPanel`. `Content panes` use `BorderLayout` by default. "

Comment: I'm not using any JPanels.  I have a static void main in one .java file which initializes the main document labMain.java.  the labMain class extends the Frame class.  Inside the labMain class I have a method runLab() which contains one Timer that checks for mouse hovering over boxes in the GUI, and also updates the graphics with paint(getGraphics()) (I'm using Graphics2D + BufferedImage).  I'll post the code in my original question for clarity.

Comment: You think "This program is intended for internal use, so it will only be used on one computer.". I once believed a manager who told me that a function I was writing would never have to read more than 200 punch cards, and used a simple data structure that made it O(n^2) time. Big mistake. I would watch people loading in a couple of thousand card boxes, and hear the card reader slow down as the data structure got bigger. I couldn't get them to let me rewrite it because it was "working". Are you sure your program will be obsolete before the computer get upgraded?

Comment: I'm actually one of the "higher ups".  We are a student run design team at a university, so we can't afford to pay for professional software.  Since I know enough Java to get by, I thought writing this would help us track our lab work and inventory.  It's really only going to be used on the computer in our lab.  If I ever need to, I can always change the way the graphics are laid out later, but for now I would like to get the software done as soon as possible so it has the basic things before getting fancy with the GUI.  I was even considering allowing input from the command line.

Comment: But I don't know if that would work when I exported the software to a stand-alone .exe

Answer (score 2):

To set Position simply  use this code

```
               import java.awt.*;
               import javax.swing.*;

                 class SetTextfield extends JFrame
                 {

                    JTextField t1,t2;
                 public SetTextfield()
                 {
                   t1=new JTextfield();
                   t2=new JTextField();
                   t1.setBounds(100,100,200,40);
                   t2.setBounds(180,100,200,40);
                   add(t1);
                    add(t2);
                  }
                  public static void main(String []args)
                  {
                     SetTextfield obj=new SetTextfield();
                      obj.setSize(500,500);
                      obj.setVisible(true);
                       obj.setResizable(false);
                  }
                  }
```

Comment: the t1.setBounds(#, #, #, #) is xpos, ypos, width, and height of the JTextField right?

Comment: yes t1.setBounds(#,#,#,#)is xposition ypos and width and height of JTextField And this x,y position is taken as referance Left upper cornerof your pc as(0,0)

Comment: Hey, I was sucessfully able to add the text field, but the problem is that my paint keeps covering it up (the Timer repaints the screen constantly).  Is there a way to bring it to the front of the graphics buffer and keep it there?  Normally the objects I use have a paint(Graphics2D g) method, so I just paint them over the background, but JTextField doesn't have it.

Comment: No I want to make sure the text field doesn't get covered by the background.  Right now I add the text field when the user clicks a certain button, but it gets covered up right away by the background.  What I'm asking is if there is a way to keep the JTextField in the foreground so it isn't being painted over by the background.

Comment: no Textfield can not be keep in foreground or background..it always appear as white color..and when you use obj.setBackground(Color.gray)as you wish, then only your background color will be painted not your text field covered..and if you want to change you button color label color then it can be changed by using this l1.setBackground(Color.red)for label and b1.setBackground(Color.yellow)for the Button..